# Thunderbird add original sender as Reply-to when forwarding

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there any way to keep original sender when forwarding message in thunderbird?
Or at least set him as Reply-To, so next person in company can just click reply and send mail to him, not to me. 
And keep all previous discussion below :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i exactly needed:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/mailredirect/

Comment: By chance did not you find a solution which would put the original sender to the `Reply-To:` header? Changing of the `From:` address performed during the bouncing (the Mail Redirect plug-in) must be enabled on the MTA. I already have a question here: [How to forward an e-mail and add the original sender to Reply-To?](http://superuser.com/q/674607/61370). --- BTW I think that your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow which is about programming.